# How do I allow my code to spend up to $35 in gas?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have an escrow smart contract takes a token from a players' wallet. On my last deployment some months ago, It worked well and took a maximum. of $6 gas when gas price was around 10 gwei. When I deployed now that gas is 35 gwei, same function fails. Same function in the contract, same javascript function too.

Last time, when I call the function from etherscan directly, it took between $3 and $6. Now, it takes between $18 and $30 on etherscan. So, I decided to pay it but the transaction keeps failing.

Details. for context.

Here is the solidity function being called

```
/**
     * @dev Submit bets for a new game.
     * @param gameId Identifier for the game
     * @param _players Array of player addresses
     * @param bets Array of bet amounts corresponding to players
     * @return true if bets are successfully submitted
     */
    function submitBets(
        uint256 gameId,
        address[] memory _players,
        uint256[] memory bets
    ) external onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(_players.length > 1, "There must be more than 1 player");
        require(_players.length == bets.length, "Array Length Does not Match");

        require(areAllBetsEqual(bets), "All bet amounts must be the same");
        require(!isGameInProgress(gameId), "Game is in Progress");

        uint256 totalSum = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _players.length; i++) {
            require(
                token.allowance(_players[i], address(this)) >= bets[i],
                "Not enough allowance"
            );

            // Add player to the current game
            playersInGame[gameId].push(_players[i]);

            token.transferFrom(_players[i], address(this), bets[i]);
            totalSum += bets[i];
        }
        games[gameId] = Game(true, totalSum);

        emit BetSubmitted(gameId, playersInGame[gameId], totalSum);
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the Javascript function.

```
export async function callNewGame(betId, addresses, bets) {
    try {
        const ownerAddress = bufferToHex(privateToAddress(toBuffer(privateKey)));
        const data = escrowContract.methods.submitBets(betId, addresses, bets).encodeABI();
        const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(ownerAddress);
        const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        
        const gasPrice120Percent = web3.utils.toHex((BigInt(gasPrice) * BigInt(1200)) / BigInt(1000));
        const txObject = {
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(3000000),
            gasPrice: gasPrice120Percent,
            to: escrowAdress,
            chainId: 1,
            data: data,
        };

        const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey);
        

        if (receipt.status == true) {
            return { status: true, hash: receipt.transactionHash };
        } else {
            console.error("Transaction failed");
            console.error("Transaction receipt:", receipt, receipt.status);
            return { status: false };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return { status: false };
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x***** have 35506820790388687 want 76938519048000000 (supplied gas 3000000)',
signature: undefined,
  receipt: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  code: 402
}
```

When I change gasLimit to 300000, error is

```
TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
```

Can anyone help me modify this so that it allows up to $35 in gas

I tried changing the gasLimit. Whenever I did, I start getting the TransactionRevert error

Answer (score 0):

EIP1559 allows you to do this. You will need to construct the EIP 1559 transaction by altering your `txObject` based on the library you use. (You are essentially writing a gas oracle).

So to spend a max of $35:

1. Get you average gas usage/max usage for that particular transaction (You can *estimate* this from previous transactions on Etherscan). Since you have not provided that value I'll assume it to be **500k** gas units. Note that this value will gradually rise seeing that there are loops over growing arrays in your smart contract.
2. Decide on a `priorityFee` also known as a `minerTip`. You will always pay this fee. This value can be fine-tuned based on network conditions but I'll pick **1 gwei** as it is suggested by Etherscan.
3. Get the current Ethereum price. At the time of writing this answer it is **$1780**. $35 translates to ~0.01966 ETH.
4. Finally determine **baseFee** given: `(baseFee + 1) * 500k = 0.01966 ETH`. Given the above params, we arrive at **38.32 gwei** to be set as the base fee.

You need to keep in mind that every value, except the priorityFee, changes every few seconds.